# Proving Borel measurability of a function.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $f(x, \cdot)$ is Borel-measurable for each $x$, and $f(\cdot, y)$ is continuous for every $y$.

Define $f_n: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f_n(x,y) = f\big(\frac{\lfloor nx \rfloor}{n}, y \big).$ I want to show that $f_n$ is Borel-measurable, but I'm not sure how to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: @ryan221b but if we work based on composition we still have that $f_n(x, \cdot)$ is Borel-measurable for each $x$ but not necessarily that $f_n$ is Borel, right?

Comment: @ryan221b can you link me to a proof of that fact?

Comment: @ryan221b also how are you projecting onto coordinates? The function is to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @ryan221b is there a proof of just that fact? I'm looking at Folland's but I don't know enough terminology to understand the generality with which he deals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f_n(x,y)=\sum_k I_{[\frac k n, \frac {k+1} n)}(x) f(\frac k n , y)$. If you multiply a measurable function of $x$ by a measurable function of $y$ you get a measurable function of $(x,y)$. Can you complete the argument?

Comment: What is $I_{[\frac{k}{n}, \frac{k+1}{n})} (x)$?

Comment: @Airdish $I_A(x)=1$ if $x \in A$ and $0$ if $x \notin A$.